# excel formula IF minimum 100 percent value

Tags: excel, formula

I have a formula that is working for some cells and not others, using this i get most but i dont want it to exceed 100% any help appreciated.

H4 is the sign in usage, I4 is the non sign in usage

Formula

```
    =IF(I4=0,--(H4>0),H4/I4-1)
```

Data

```
                   H4  I4   % percentage of usage
    Ashtabula OH    3   8   -63%
    Atlanta GA     18   7   157%
    Augusta GA     11   2   450%
    Avon IN        28   12  133%  
    Baldwin FL     0    22  -100%  <--accurate, shows no usage at all
    Birmingham AL  21   1   2000%  <--not accurate
    Bronx NY       0    19  -100%
    Brunswick MD   0    47  -100%
    Buffalo NY     0    16  -100%
    Charlotte NC  29    1   2800%
    ChattanoogaTN  5    0   100%   <--most accurate positive value if everyone used the machine this would be 100% percent for all locations
```

Photo:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your formula in MIN()

```
=MIN(IF(I4=0,--(H4>0),H4/I4-1),1)
```

Comment: this one didnt work for all, i cant add images directly but there is a link,

Comment: You stated that you do not want to exceed 100% and it does not.  Why is it wrong?

Comment: 1 percent of 29 is 3.45  so the usage would be 96.55% update: the picture i posted is using your formula. Scott

Comment: your own formula is the one that is wrong then  You do `29/1 - 1` which is greater than 100%  So you actually want  `(29-1)/29` which will get you the `96.55`?

Comment: Your right sir,, I need to create another column of total usage and then get the percentage value from usage vs no usage. Many thanks, Ill show it answered.

Comment: Try this formula: `=IF(H4=0,--(I4=0),(H4-I4)/H4)`

Comment: or does this more accurately dipict what you want: `=H4/(H4+I4)`